# Android studio could not find class path

Tags: java, android

I have got a error with my project in the android studio, there is a classpath that could not be modified, the class path is

```
dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
             }
```

the dependences are

```
dependencies {   
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'    
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])     
  androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
  core:2.2.2', {      
  exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 
   'support-annotations'     
                })       
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'        
  compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'        
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'         
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'         
  compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'       
  compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.1'    
  compile 'com.android.support:recylcerview-v7:26+'     
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'     
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:1.2.0'     
 compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.2.0'     
 compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:10.2.0'    
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.6'     
 testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

and I have added this

```
        maven {  url "https://maven.google.com"    }
```

in the Gradle.

Comment: post your `module:gradle`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classpath should be added in **app** level `build.gradle` not in module `build.gradle`

```
dependencies { 
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
}
```

Please add this line in `build.gradle`(Project:yourappname)

Comment: I have don so, and an other error had appeared for me : Error:(1, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.